# How to enable datetimepicker in bootstrap-jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Here I'm trying to use bootstrap-jquery datetimepicker for my form. but unfortunately I'm getting an error that datetimepicker undefined function. here is my code 
`

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Script for datepickers i.e. startdate and enddate -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
      todayHighlight: true,
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      startDate: new Date()   
     });
    </script>`
```

ERROR:: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Any help that would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to set it up after page load?  like `$(document).ready(function() { $('#date').datetimepicker ... });`

Comment: Read from here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) and [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) are two unrelated projects - which one are you trying to use?

Comment: @Tieson T I would like to use bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Okay, then you need to fix your code, per https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ - those two plugins don't work the same. If all you're using are dates, though, you're better off using the bootstrap-datepicker plugin.

Comment: Do you have any idea that how to dump https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ with composer in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out exactly what is the Error since you didn't post the Full Code , but i managed to install a [Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzZEPE) for you this may help . Also some tips Bootstrap-datepicker Requires jQuery and Bootstrap , so by calling those dependencies you will be good to go :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js
```

Latest Bootstrap-datepicker Version :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css
```

One more thing make sure your Code is executing after Page finish loading .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //your code here
})
```